# Print the time a command was used into Terminal. -Discord.py (Rewrite)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am currently writing a discord bot with python (Rewrite) and I want to print the time of which a command was used and what command it was into the terminal.

```
import sys, discord, random, os, datetime, time
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ';')



# Startup

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Commands is online.')

def ConsoleCMD(cmd):
    print((datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')),f"\tSomeone used the '{cmd}' command!")


# ----I'm not sure if this is necessary but I'll include it just in case----

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
    print('Loaded')

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
    print('Unloaded')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

#----------------


# Commands

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Testing, Testing 1 2 3')
    ConsoleCMD(test)

client.run('Insert ID here')
```

The main file works, but when I include the cogs, it doesn't

This is the one of the cogs:

```
import discord, time, os, sys, datetime
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime

class Fun(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    # Events

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Fun is online.')

    def ConsoleCMD(cmd):
        print((datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')),f"\tSomeone used the '{cmd}' command!")


    # Commands

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Pong!')
        ConsoleCMD(ping)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Fun(client))
```

This is the output:

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'ConsoleCMD' is not defined

Comment: if you're planning on doing this for every command it might be smart to use the on_command event so you don't have to repeat the code for every command

Answer (score 1):

The function you made was in a class and has to be called through the class. Check out [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-osiE80TeTsqhIuOqKhwlXsIBIdSeYtc) by Corey Schafer for a better understanding of classes and OOP. 
To make this work you have to call the method with self and also add `self` as a parameter to ConsoleCMD

```py
def ConsoleCMD(self, cmd):
    print((datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')),f"\tSomeone used the '{cmd}' command!")

@commands.command()
async def ping(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong!')
    self.ConsoleCMD(self, "ping")
```